# Yes/No Menu Using Characters Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: c#, io, console-application

I'm trying to make a simple menu where you select one option or the other to proceed. Instead of "yes" or "no" this menu uses "read" or "write" as the two options but the concept is of course the same. The code looks like this...

```
public void Start()
    {
        char selection;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to read (r) or write (w) to a file?");
            selection = (char) Console.Read();
        } while (selection != 'r' || selection != 'w');
    }
```

Now not only does this not stop looping when you DO type in either 'r' or 'w' but it types out 3 lines of the WriteLine text after you press enter anytime after.

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix this? I'm assuming I'm improperly using the Read() method but being the newbie that I am I find it hard to simply trial and error my way through some things. Any help at all would be amazing. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

```
public void Start()
    {
        char selection = 'y';
        while(selection == 'y')
        {
            Console.Write("Would you like to continue...");
            selection = (char)Console.Read();
            Flush();
        }
    }

public void Flush()
    {
        while(Console.In.Peek() != -1)
        {
            Console.In.Read();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console.Read() will give you the characters as they are typed. As soon as they type the 'r' is stops. Isn't that what you want?
Hitting ENTER actually generates 2 characters, so it will print out the prompt 2 more times. 
Maybe you just want this:

```
public void Start()
{
    char selection;
    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to read (r) or write (w) to a file?");
    do
    {
        selection = (char) Console.Read();
    } while (selection != 'r' && selection != 'w');
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it certainly stopped the Text from reappearing multiple times but it didn't quite seem to work any better than the other had. This still failed to end the program when the improper keys were struck. (typically when the while loop has no reason to continue it breaks and with no more code to run the app stops) it just allowed me to continue typing... However I seem to have found a work around, see my edit please. This works perfectly... but I don't for sure understand why can you give me any insight as to why this works? I had to change the code up a bit to make it work but...

Comment: you never said you wanted it to end when improper characters were typed. That's unusual behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`selection != 'r' || selection != 'w'` is always true. If `selection` is `r`, then the `selection != 'w'` part is true, and if `selection` is not `r`, then the `selection != 'r'` part is true, so you either have `false || true` (which is true), or `true || ...` (the latter operand doesn't matter) which is also true.

You probably want `while (selection != 'r' && selection != 'w')`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve your question is break the loop with a break call and then return the inserted value.
Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char selection = read_or_write();
        Console.WriteLine("char in main function: "+selection);
        Console.WriteLine("press enter to close");
        Console.ReadLine(); //clean with enter keyboard
    }
    public static char read_or_write()
    {
        char selection;
        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to read (r) or write (w) to a file?");
        do
        {
            selection = (char)Console.Read();
            Console.ReadLine();//clean with enter keyboard
            if (selection == 'r')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed r");
                break;
            }
            else if (selection == 'w')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed w");
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You pressed a wrong key!");
            }
        } while (selection != 'r' || selection != 'w');
        return selection;
    }
}
```